# How to gather a tensor from Keras using its backend?

Tags: keras, backend

I trying to compile a model in Keras with an input that is a 2D numpy array.
What I need is to take the vector at the nth place of this 2D array and use it as a tensor 1D tensor for one of the layers. 
How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lambda layer should do it:

```
extracted_tensor = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,nth_index,:], output_shape=(1,dim_vector))(input)
extracted_tensor = Flatten()(extracted_tensor)
```

note that in the `x` tensor (lambda function), you take the batch dimension into account, but you don't in the output_shape parameter.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.gather( input_tensor, indices, axis )` to collect `indices` along the specified `axis`.